# Laravel: how to fixed Null input when i add a variable from jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-8

I have this

```
<input type="number" disabled  name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="0.00" >
```

and this Jquery

```
$('#amount').val(100);
```

it goes smoothly and it shows in the UI. my problem is when I submit the button the value of `$request->amount` is `null`? how can I fix it? please help and save my day guys. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `disabled` use  `readonly`

```
<input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="0.00" readonly>
```